# How to remove image border in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to put this image on the canvas, only without borders, or with the border of the canvas color. I already put border size = 0 but it didn't work.
What do I do please?

```
image1 = Image.open("imagem2.png")
image = image1.resize((120, 120), Image.ANTIALIAS)
test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


label1 = ttk.Label(image=test, borderwidth=0)
label1.image = test


# Position image
label1.place(x=0, y=230)
```

[I would like to take these edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOqe2.png)

Comment: unknown option "-highlightthickness"

Comment: Sorry, that's for canvas. Does it need to be a label?

Comment: Not all themes support changing `borderwidth`, try using other theme like `alt` or `clam`.  Or using `tkinter.Label` instead of `ttk.Label`.